# MATLAB Trigonometry Find Field

Tags: matlab, plot, field, trigonometry, graphic

I have this trigonometric equation;

`cos(2*pi*50*t)+cos(2*pi*100*t)`

I want to graphic of equation and I want to find field for a period. How can I do?

[image]

Comment: What does "find field" mean in this context?

Comment: Example;
I have rectangle. `Short side lenght: 10 cm` and `Long side lenght: 20 cm`
`Rectangle field = 10 cm x 20 cm = 200 cm^2`

Comment: So you mean [area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Area)?

Comment: Yes. Are area and field different?

Comment: Not different. I've just never heard field used in that context before. Why do you need to do this graphically when you can do it analytically with integrals?

Comment: I need both. Graphic and area.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Graph:

```
>> f = @(t) cos(2*pi*50*t) + cos(2*pi*100*t);
>> x = linspace(0, 1/50, 100);
>> y = f(x);
>> plot(x,y)
```

Area over 1 period:

```
>> integral(f, 0, 1/50)
```

or just do it manually:

```
∫ ( cos(2π·50t) + cos(2π·100t) ) dt = 
-1/2π·( 1/50·sin(2π·50t) + 1/100·sin(2π·100t) )
```

which, evaluated between 0 and 1/50, equals 0.

Comment: Good answer but I have problem. Yes, I find equals 0. Area below zero is negative. I want this to be positive too. I shared picture. I want to find the scanned area.

Comment: Take the absolute value of the output and find the integral.